# Return confirm function does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I generate some buttons dynamically with php like this:

```
<?php
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
    echo "<tr>
        <td><a href='updateproject.php?id=$row[ID]' class='btn btn-warning btn-mini'>
            <i class='icon-white icon-pencil'></i>
            </a>
            <a href='deleterow.php?del=$row[ID]' onclick='return confirm('You want to delete this?');' class='btn btn-danger btn-mini'>
            <i class='icon-white icon-remove'></i>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>{$row['Projectname']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Personincharge']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Description']}</td>
        <td>{$row['CreationDate']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Location']}</td>                             
    </tr>\n";
}
?>
```

I have tried so many things but it doesn't work. No alert is coming. It just getting deleted...

Comment: This "onclick=return confirm" creates an box. Got it from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyKRsJvmshE

Comment: That's the exact syntax they show you to use in that video?

Comment: No but I can not use this " otherwise I get errors because I am giving an echo...

Comment: I was going to comment about using escaped `"` for `onclick=\"` instead of `onclick='` See the answers below. Ben's answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your slashes will be breaking as it'll think the statement ends at `confirm('`. Try this:

```
onclick=\"return confirm('You want to delete this?');\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate the table in a form and use the following code.

```
<form onsubmit=" return window.confirm('Are you sure?');">

  <?php
      //Add button php here and fields  
  ?>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.delete').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    confirm('You want to delete this?');
    });
});
```

```
//db connection goes here

$query = mysql_query("Select * FROM `table_name`");

echo "<table>";
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ){

echo
"<tr>   
<td> <a href='deleterow.php?del={$row['id']}' class='delete'>Delete</a>
</td>
<td>{$row['Projectname']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Personincharge']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Description']}</td>
    <td>{$row['CreationDate']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Location']}</td>                      
</tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>";
```